# div vs li when to use them

Tags: html, css

Hi I have about six months experience in web development.
I have the following observation,
I use `<div>` tags a lot, it gives me the ability to position the elements, to archive the elements,
and it seems I can use `<div>` tags to do everything, simply playing with its display property.

I've never had to use `<ul>` or `<li>` elements in combination, except for horizontal menu navigation, and I am not sure why you can't do it with `<div>` elements, but it seems to be the 'convention' for achieving a horizontal menu.

Did I miss something?  Are there some properties that `<li>` elements have that are better or more useful than `<div>` elements?

<sub>Please don't restrict this question to only horizontal menu list; I want to know any scenario where you would use a `<li>` over something else.</sub>

Comment: "did i miss something" = yes. Semantics. Google "semantic web" to learn a bit more about it. Basically, use the right tag for the right content. DIVs can work, but are usually the last option you should go with as they have the least semantic meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do anything (more or less) strictly with div tags (with exceptions, like forms and inputs, and images, and what not).  But that's not the point.

First, specific tags have default css applied to them.  li's have bullets, for example.  You can change these, but in many situations, it's just easier to use the tag that has the style you're looking for.

But the most important reason is what's called "semantic markup", which is the concept that which element you use corresponds to a semantic meaning.  li means it's a list of items, so even if you have no CSS applied (such as when a screen reader reads a page aloud for blind person) then it still has meaning.

Answer (score 4):

The only reason to use one tag over another is semantics. The purpose of HTML syntax is to provide meaning to the content that is being rendered.

A `<ul>` element is an unordered list. It means the content is a collection of items where order is unimportant.

A `<div>` element is simply a structural element with no semantics associated with it. You could certainly use `<div>` elements to create the styles typically associated with `<ul>` elements, but it would mean losing the inherent semantics of the original element.

If you wanted to maintain the original semantics with `<div>` elements, you could use the [`list` role](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#list):

```
<div role="list">
    <div role="listitem">...content...</div>
    <div role="listitem">...content...</div>
    <div role="listitem">...content...</div>
</div>
```

However, the WAI-ARIA roles model isn't very well supported, so you'd be better off using the basic markup of:

```
<ul>
    <li>...content...</li>
    <li>...content...</li>
    <li>...content...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML tags should help to explain the intent of the layout. When you use div for everything, it says nothing about the content. ul/li makes it clear that you have a list of related items.

This was the motivation for the addition of many new tags in HTML5: to make the layout have more semantics, that make it more understandable to humans maintaining the code, and to screen readers. So yes, you can make a page look the way you want with only div's, but it will be harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Now depends your needs you can use any tag for example if you want to create a custom select is not ok to use div because is more useful to use ul li, check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/RwtHn/1152/
Now if you want to determine a section in which you want to add different paragaphs, pics or other static elements is more that ok to use divs. Check this for ul li : http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html   andthis for divs: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/div . Is not a rule when to use what to use but it an help you in web development if you are codding well.
Cheers.